# pandas count frequency of column value in another dataframe column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to calculate the frequencies of values of a dataframe column in a column from another dataframe. Right now, I have the code as below:

```
df2["freq"] = df1[["col1"]].groupby(df2["col2"])["col1"].transform('count')
```

But it is giving freq of 1.0 for all the values in df2["col2"], even for those values that don't exist in df1["col1"].

df1:

```
            col1
0            636  
1            636  
2            801  
3            802
```

df2:

```
            col2
0            636  
1            734  
2            801  
3            803
```

df2 after adding freq column:

```
            col2    freq
0            636    1.0
1            734    1.0
2            801    1.0
3            803    1.0
```

What I actually want:

```
            col2    freq
0            636     2
1            734     0
2            801     1
3            803     0
```

I am new to pandas, so I am not getting what I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Can you add some data samples, 3-5 rows for both?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by " in a column from another dataframe". Because you can get a frequency distribution easily: `your_column.value_counts()`

Comment: @jezrael I have updated the question to include dataframes. Hopefully my question is clear now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by Series created by [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html), last replace missing values to `0`:

```
df2["freq"] = df2["col2"].map(df1["col1"].value_counts()).fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df2)
   col2  freq
0   636     2
1   734     0
2   801     1
3   803     0
```